# Weird behaviour of Object.create()

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

Can somebody explain what is going on here:
code sample 1:

```
o2={b:10};
function classCreate(proto,o){
    return Object.create(proto,o);
}
var o1=classCreate({a:o2},{});
console.log(o1.a.b);  // prints 10
```

code sample 2:

```
o2={b:10};
function classCreate(proto,o){
    return Object.create(proto,o);
}
var o1=classCreate({},{a:o2});
console.log(o1.a.b);  //reference error
```

How does Object.create manage to mangle its scope when extending the final object?

Comment: Look at [Object.defineProperties()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) and [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: What does this have to do with scope? Btw, `var classCreate = Object.create`, no additional function needed.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in `Object.create` should be an object of properties given in a very strict format. For example this would work:

```
var o1 = classCreate({}, {a: {value: o2}});
```

Read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties